# Как определить innodb или myisam?

Tags: mysql

Как определить, на каком движке сделана БД?

Comment: @tfox, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

БД - это набор таблиц. Таблицы могут быть как InnoDB, так и MyISAM (или даже другие). Т.е. нельзя сказать - "*БД у меня MyISAM*". Можно сказать "*Для таблицы A использована подсистема хранения InnoDB, а для таблицы B - подсистема хранения MyISAM*"

А узнать какая подсистема хранения используется для таблицы можно, например, через `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` ([см. доки](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html))